# Why do I get this displaying?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        {{#linkTo "projects"}}Root{{/linkTo}}
        {{#each controller}}
          <div class="span4">
            {{#linkTo "projects.show" this}}{{this.name}}{{/linkTo}}
          </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

And:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects/show">
    <h2>Overview of {{name}}</h2>
  </script>
```

and the following content in app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  key : DS.attr("string")
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("projects",function() {
    this.route("show", {path: "/:project_id"});
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo("projects");
  }
});

App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("project");
  },
})
```

and the following model setup:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter // run with fixture data
});

App.Project.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Proj1',
    key: "P1KEY"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Proj2',
    key: "P2KEY"
  },
];
```

When I first navigate to the page, I see the following 3 links ( Root, Proj1, and Proj2 ). Since I'm in the index view initially, I see this:

[image]

Then, I click on the first project, and I see this:

[image]

And, finally I go back to the index, but the contents of the project/show seem to still be there:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say go back to index, are you saying you click the Root link?  It looks like it works to me:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IBECuSID/1/edit

BTW, I went up to a newer version of Ember Data, so a minor change:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

Comment: I'll be damned! It worked for me also, after I added the application template ... and then I removed it, and now my version also works. I tried cleaning my assets/browser cache, and it still works. Strange stuff :)